# Is it possible to give a dynamic value in startagy matrix github actions?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have the following workflow and want to pass some dynamic value in startagy matrix:

```
env:
  FORMULA: testFormula
jobs:
   test:
     name: Test for ${{ matrix.os }}
     runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
     strategy:
       fail-fast: false
       matrix:
         include:
           - os: ubuntu-latest
             asset_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }}-${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}
             command_name: echo "matrix1"
           - os: ubuntu-latest
             artifact_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }}_${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}-1_amd64.deb
             asset_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }}-${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}.deb
             command_name: echo "matrix2"
           - os: macos-latest
             artifact_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }-v${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}-x86.exe
             asset_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }}-${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}.exe
             command_name: echo "matrix3"
           - os: macos-latest
             artifact_name: macos/${{ env.FORMULA }-v${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}.pkg
             asset_name: ${{ env.FORMULA }}-${{ steps.get-tag.outputs.TAG_NAME }}.pkg
             command_name: echo "matrix4"

     steps:
       - name: Getting latest tag
         id: get-tag
         run: |
           echo "::set-output name=TAG_NAME::2.3.4)"
```

and I am using the strategy matrix below to run somethings. But I am getting error

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/test.yml : Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.FORMULA
```

Please help me how to pass dynamic values to strategy matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually [shown in the GitHub Actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-returning-a-json-object).

To gloss what's described there, you construct a JSON object that has the form of what's expected by the `matrix` key (string names/keys that have array values). Then you set the serialized JSON as an output and refer to it in your matrix job. Like so:

```
generate-build-matrix:
    # one of each build category must be set
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix:  ${{ steps.create-matrix.outputs.matrix }}steps:
    steps:
    - name: Create matrix object
        id: create-matrix
        shell: python
        run: |
          from os import getenv
          from subprocess import Popen
          import json
          matrix_obj = {"prod-environment":[], "nice-app":[], "app-platform": []}
          if getenv("ENV_PRODUCTION").lower() == "true":
            matrix_obj["prod-environment"].append("production")
          ...
          if getenv("APP_GA").lower() == "true":
            matrix_obj["nice-app"].append("ga")
          matrix_str = f'::set-output name=matrix::{json.dumps(matrix_obj)}'
          print(f"Final matrix string: {matrix_str}") 
          Popen(['echo', matrix_str], bufsize=1)
        env:
          ENV_PRODUCTION: ${{inputs.env-production}}
          APP_GA: ${{inputs.app-ga}} 
          ...

matrix-job:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{fromJSON(needs.generate-build-matrix.outputs.matrix)}}
    name: My matrix job
...
```